# How to combine 4 the same functions into one new function that can be reused

Tags: javascript, function

I made some functions, but they are all doing approximately the same thing.
I would like to combine those functions into one new function that can be reused in case i need one more new function like this.. Is it possible to do so or am i just wasting your and my time?

**Here is the code:**

```
function getBinding(selectedBinding) {
  var b = elems.binding;
  var selectedBinding = b.options[b.selectedIndex].value;
  return selectedBinding;
} 

// Getting the holes value
function getHoles(selectedHoles) {
  var h = elems.holes;
  var selectedHoles = h.options[h.selectedIndex].value;
  return selectedHoles;
}

// Getting the paper weight value
function getPaperWeight(selectedPaperWeight) {
  var pW = elems.paperWeight;
  var selectedPaperWeight = pW.options[pW.selectedIndex].value;
  return selectedPaperWeight;
}

// Getting the staples value
function getStaples(selectedStapling) {
  var s = elems.stapling;
  var selectedStapling = s.options[s.selectedIndex].value;
  return selectedStapling;
}
```

any suggestions?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The parameters of all the functions don't have any use based on your code.

Comment: what is the purpose of parameter `selectedBinding`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take the element as parameter.

```
function getValue(element) {
    var e = elems[element];
    return e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like `getByKey`?

```js
// 
function getValueByKey(key) {
  var elem = elems[key];
  var optionValue = elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].value;
  return optionValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would get the prop type as parameters -

```
function selectByPropAndIndex(prop){
    var elemByProp = elems[prop];
    var selected= elemByProp.options[elemByProp.selectedIndex].value;
    return selected;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [partial application](http://benalman.com/news/2012/09/partial-application-in-javascript/) to create this kind of functions:

```
function getItems(elementType) {
  return function(elements) {
    var items = elements[elementType];
    return items.options[items.selectedIndex].value;
  };
}

var getBinding = getItems('binding');
var getHoles = getItems('holes');
var getPaperWeight = getItems('paperWeight');
var getStaples = getItems('stapling');
```

Usage:

```
getBinding(elems);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
function getSelectedProperty(property) {
    var elem = elems[property];
    return elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].value;
}
```

Note also that your original code has some problem. The parameters are useless because you are defining a new variable inside each function that would override the parameter name because you gave it the same name. As an example:

```
function foo(x) {
    var x = 5; // this x is not the same as the parameter x
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getBinding(selectedElement, type) {
    switch(type) {
        case binding:
            var element = elems.binding;
            break;
        case hole:
            var element = elems.holes;
            break;
        case paper:
            var element = elems.paperWeight;
            break;
        case staples:
            var element = elems.stapling;
            break;
    }
    var selectedElement = element.options[element.selectedIndex].value;
    return selectedElement;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how i fixed it!

```
function getValue(selector){ 
    return parseInt(selector.options[selector.selectedIndex].value);
};
```

Thanks all!